# How can I parse this json array? It seems to be an object

Tags: php, arrays, json

Hope you can help. I've searched but to no avail. I need to know how to read this json array into seperate php variables and then add it to a MySQL table:-

```
stdClass Object
(
    [status] => ok
    [search] => search_data
    [pagination] => Array
        (
            [next] => /search/data/?query=landrover&limit=3
        )

    [data] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [domain] => fourwheeler.com
                    [description] => Landrover
                    [user] => Array
                        (
                            [username] => jlyon
                            [full_name] => j lyon
                            [image_url] => http://example.jpg
                            [id] => 200902970785661194
                        )
                    [counts] => Array
                        (
                            [datacount] => 4
                            [comments] => 0
                            [likes] => 0
                        )
                    [id] => 200902833346737840
                    [created_at] => 2011-08-30T05:23:45
                )
            [1] => Array
                (
                    [domain] => 4x4forum.co.uk
                    [description] => Defender
                    [user] => Array
                        (
                            [username] => tjeffries
                            [full_name] => T Jeffries
                            [image_url] => http://example.jpg
                            [id] => 200902970785661194
                        )
                    [counts] => Array
                        (
                            [datacount] => 3
                            [comments] => 2
                            [likes] => 34
                        )
                    [id] => 200902833346737840
                    [created_at] => 2011-09-02T05:12:57
                )

            [2] => Array
                (
                    [domain] => tumblr.com
                    [description] => rangerover
                    [user] => Array
                        (
                            [username] => pjackson
                            [full_name] => p jackson
                            [image_url] => http://example.jpg
                            [id] => 200902970785661194
                        )
                    [counts] => Array
                        (
                            [datacount] => 24
                            [comments] => 3
                            [likes] => 9
                        )
                    [id] => 200902810506737091
                    [created_at] => 2011-09-230T05:19:35
                )

        )

    [query] => landrover
    [counts] => Array
        (
            [places] => 3
            [datapoints] => 500
            [user] => 0
        )

    [pages] => 3
)
```

I have tried doing this but had no luck.

```
$JSON_Data = json_decode($JSON,true);

foreach($json_output['data'] as $key => $val) {

$domain = ($json_output['data'][$key]['domain']);   
echo $domain."<br/>";
}
```

Can anyone help so that I can sleep tonight without tearing my hair out? ;-)

Thanks

Jonatan

Comment: The first snippet isn't JSON. JSON is a string.

Comment: What you posted is not a JSON array

Comment: Perhaps you need to look more at Iterators in php? and see if you can iterate over the object?

Comment: Are you sure youre iterating over the correct variable cause there is definitely a typo in your post. passing `true` as that second arg should take car of keeping everything an array even if its an object in JS.

Comment: @Ignacio,Mchl: I think its ok to assume what he posted is the result of `json_decode` on the json string.

Comment: I remember when people on Stackoverflow would rather help and answer a question rather than simply just comment for commenting's sake

Answer (score 0):

What you copied in your question is an object. Is that what you are using json_decode() on, because that won't work. It's already and object, and you just need to iterate over the object (actually, it's a mixture of arrays in an object).

I'd adjust the code you included to read like this:

```
//assuming $JSON is not an object already. If it is, ignore this line:
$jsonData = json_decode($JSON); 

foreach($jsonData->data as $val) {
   echo $val['domain'] . '<br/>';
}
```

Comment: I finally figured it out, I used foreach($json_output->{'data'} as $val){

    echo $val->domain."<br/>";

}

Comment: Yeah, that's basically a slightly different way of saying the same thing, although you used different variable names. In your var_dump $val was an array, but it looks like you ended up getting it from an object.